# Do I need to send the XSD files with WSDL for implementation

Tags: wcf, xsd

I am developing a WCF service in .net and would like to give the wsdl file to the customer who can consume our service. I successfully Generated the wsdl which includes the xsd import statement

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="https://URL/Service-v1.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="Service-v1" /> 
<xsd:import schemaLocation="https://URL/PricingService-v1.svc?xsd=xsd3"  />
```

etc

**But what I would like to know is is that is enough to just send the wsdl to the customer or do I need to send them the XSD files as well..**

How can I generate separate XSD files for each class like class1.xsd, class2.xsd, class3.xsd

here is my project structure
**DataModel**
  Class1.cs
  Class2.cs
  Class3.cs
  Response.cs
**Contract**
  IService1 with the following contracts
    Response GetQuote1(Class1 class1Request);
    Response GetQuote2(Class2 class2Request);
    Response GetQuote2(Class2 class2Request);

**Service**
 Service1 : Iservice1

```
  public Response GetQuote1(Class1 class1Request)
  {
          return response;
  }

  public Response GetQuote2(Class2 class2Request)
  {
          return response;
  }

  public Response GetQuote3(Class3 class3Request)
  {
          return response;
  }
```

I search on the internet but couldn't be able to decide on the best option as we have no control over the other end who is going to implement our WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about .net but I have had experience both consuming and providing web services to 3rd parties.

The WSDL is basically a list of functions that can be called on a remote server and how to connect. Each function is going to have an XML format for the request and response. It is possible to embed the schema for these in the WSDL itself. If this is the case then you only have to send this one file. It sounds to me that your auto-generated WSDL has the schemas for the request and response params in seperate files. If this is the case then they'll need both the WSDL and XSD's.

If you just provide the WSDL then they'll know how to package up the SOAP request but they won't know the format of the XML that goes in the body. A bit like knowing someones telephone number but not knowing the language they speak, not much use! If I was the customer I would rather have just the XSD's than just the WSDL. With the inputs and outputs defined I can start coding. Then once I have access to the full WSDL and XSD's I can generate a stub to call the appropriate service and hook up the code I've already written. Of course if the XSD's and WSDL are both ready then by all means please send me the lot.

Comment: Hi Ben Yes this WSDL is autogenerated  which contains several imports of XSD files(xsd=xsd0,xsd=xsd1 etc). Is it fine to just send all those XSD files by just saving them as .XSD or do I just need to include the whole schema inside the WSDL. If that is the case how can I do that, what are the option do I have. Other Option is How can I just have the seperate XSD for each Data Contract I use in my Service Contract. Thanks

Comment: If it's been generated that way then I would leave it as seperate files. It makes sense to seperate them out, particularly if you have a complicated WSDL with lots going on. I would send the wsdl and xsd's together in a zip folder. The 3rd party should be able to cope with that.

Comment: I will see how it goes by sending XSD with WSDL and I also just managed to flatten the wsdl using Thinktecture solution suggested and it includes all the schemal in a single wsdl but trying to figure out how to get the enumeration meta data across to the client

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET with WCF, the service description page will generally include a link such as:

```
http://localhost:12345/Foo.svc?singleWsdl
```

If you right-click and save that file from the browser, it's an all-inclusive, WSDL + schema for each call, that contains all the information a consumer would need for the service.